# WCF 3.5 UserNameAuthentication is not working?

Tags: wcf, validation, .net-3.5

What I'm trying to do is to secure my service. To do this I'm using UserNameAuthentication. I did the binding and everything but some reason when I start the service I don't get the Validation prompt! **Validate** method is not triggered!

**Here is my webConfig**

I don't know what I'm missing here!

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="IPhone.Service1Behavior" name="MobileService.IPhone">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MobileService.IIPhone" bindingConfiguration="SafeServiceConf">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="IPhone.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication
             userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
             customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MobileService.CustomValidator, MobileService" />

      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SafeServiceConf" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="65536"
         maxBytesPerRead="65536" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Here is my code in IPhone.svc for validation**

I put the CustomValidator class inside the service!

```
public class CustomValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName == "test" && password == "test")
            return;
        throw new SecurityTokenException(
            "Unknown Username or Password");
    }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation prompt would not come from WCF. The UI is responsible for that (i.e. ASPX web form).

To pass a user name and password from a client to a service, you would do something like this:

```
 proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myUserName";
 proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

Comment: I just want to secure the .svc file! I could prompt from client but what if someone access the URL directly, they could access the service right?

Comment: No, a user will not be able to call your service if you are using the UserNamePasswordValidator and they don't pass the correct ClientCredintials (i.e. UserName and Password).